# Anyone know the name of this Rabbi?

Tags: rabbis

[image: I found this rebbe card and I'm not sure who it is? thank you so much in advance!]

I found this rebbe card and I'm not sure who it is? thank you so much in advance!

Comment: I suggest that you post your question (best in Hebrew, but I'm sure it will also be understood in English) along with the picture to the following thread on the Otzar forum as it deals with identifying pictures of rabbis - זיהוי רבנים שבתמונה - https://forum.otzar.org/viewtopic.php?t=3405

Comment: Judging from the absence of wrinkles on the forehead, looks like neither answer is correct.

Comment: is anything written on the back?

Answer (score 0):

[image]Looks like it is the Klausenberg Rebbe from Boro Park

Comment: Do you know this from more than just comparing these two pictures? They look quite similar, despite the age difference, but it does seem like his eye sight improved? Or am I imagining that

Comment: @RabbiKaii At first i thought it was his brother the Sanzer Rebbe from Netanya, but after closer inspection, i believe it is the Klausenburg rebbe of Boro Park

Comment: To my eye, these two pictures don't obviously show the same person.

Comment: @DoubleAA Look at the teeth: https://gedolimpics.com/gallery/klausenberger-rebbe/#/gallery/klausenberger-rebbe/mg-klausenberger-rebbe-12/

Comment: @DoubleAA Please also keep in mind a 20+ year time diffrence between the photos

Answer (score 0):

To me this looks like Rav Shimshon David Pinkus:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Not even close.

Comment: The peyos are completely wrong.